# Escaping URL's (without double escaping)

Tags: ruby, url, browser

How do I escape a URL as needed, without double escaping?

Is there a Ruby library that already does this? I wonder what algorithm WebKit or Chrome uses.

Two examples:

- This URL is not valid, since the `%` is not escaped: `http://x.co/op&k=21%`. If you type it into the URL bar, it knows to escape it. (It is escaping the '%' behind the scenes, right?)
- If you type `http://localhost:3000/?s=hello%20world` into a browser, it knows to **not** escape `%20` again.

I want to reuse great code that has already worked the edge cases that browsers have to handle. I don't mind calling an external library if necessary.

**Update**: Yes, I know about [URI.parse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse). No need to show me the syntax. My question **is** harder than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, the winners are:

- [Addressable::URI#normalize](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/api/Addressable/URI.html#normalize-instance_method): "Returns a normalized URI object. NOTE: This method does not attempt to fully conform to specifications. It exists largely to correct other people’s failures to read the specifications, and also to deal with caching issues since several different URIs may represent the same resource and should not be cached multiple times."
- [Addressable::URI.heuristic_parse](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/api/Addressable/URI.html#heuristic_parse-class_method): "Converts an input to a URI. The input does not have to be a valid URI -- the method will use heuristics to guess what URI was intended. This is not standards-compliant, merely user-friendly."

Answer (score 0):

Knowing whether you need to encode or decode multiple times is up to you. You're the programmer and need to be aware of what state the URL is in as you massage it.

A browser can assume that a `%` not followed by a numeric-value is bare, and should be escaped. See "[Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1)" for more information.

You can use Ruby's built-in [`URI`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html), or the [Addressable::URI](http://addressable.rubyforge.org/api/) gems to encode/decode.

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://x.co/op')
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form('k' => '21%')

puts uri.to_s # => http://x.co/op?k=21%25
```

or:

```
require 'addressable/uri'

uri = Addressable::URI.parse('http://x.co/op')
uri.query_values = {'k' => '21%'}
puts uri.to_s # => "http://x.co/op?k=21%25"
```

Comment: Re: "You're the programmer and need to be aware of what state the URL is in as you massage it." Here is what I'm aware of -- I'm consuming URL's from an API that are out of my control. Some parse with `URI.parse` and some do not. I want to be forgiving on the input side. Thanks for mentioning `Addressable` -- it seems to be more forgiving.

Comment: Re: "Knowing whether you need to encode or decode multiple times is up to you." ... I think this might be a naive thing to say. Browsers handle all kinds of "URLs" -- I've seen this practice described as being "pathologically friendly!" I'm looking for a library or algorithm that already knows how to do this -- to handle the uncertainty I've described. If I'm lucky, `Addressable` will do a significantly better job than Ruby's built in `URI` -- but I would not 'expect' a low-level library to do what I need.

Comment: Re: "A browser can assume that a % not followed by a numeric-value is bare, and should be escaped." ... Right! That said, I would suspect that there are many such 'rules of thumb' that are probably already coded and tested. I want to find how WebKit or Chrome does it, rather than rolling it myself.